# Define environment `Question` when loading package `unicode-math`

Tags: unicode-math

I'm using Win10, TeXLive 2020. When I use `XeLaTeX` to compile code below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newenvironment{Question}{\textbf{envname}}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{Question}
        test
    \end{Question}
\end{document}
```

[image: load <code>unicode-math</code> 宏包]

When I change environment name or unload `unicode-math` package, I can get the correct output

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newenvironment{question}{\textbf{envname}}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{question}
        test
    \end{question}
\end{document}
```

I can get

[image: change environment name]

Why did that happen and how to fix it without changing the environment name?

Comment: You got the answer already, but I opened an issue https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/548.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Explanation

`\Question` is one of math symbol commands `unicode-math` provides. Therefore after your `\newenvivonment{Question}...`, `\Question` is redefined to the double question mark (`U+2047`) at the beginning of document (`\begin{document}`) by `unicode-math`. Since the default unicode math font Latin Modern Math font does not provide this symbol, XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX) writes

```
Missing character: There is no ⁇ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

to the log and leaves a blank before environment content `test` in the output. It is a pity that this error is not filtered by most editors.

If you move `\newenvivonment{Question}...` after `\begin{document}`, you will get

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \Question already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

which reminds you that `\Question` is already defined.

#### Workaround

Probably you need to use another environment name, or redefine `\Question` at the beginning of document like

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

% this must appear after unicode-math
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewenvironment{Question}{\textbf{envname}}{}
  % or let \Question to undefined, then \newenvironment{Question}
}
``
```

Comment: Nice overlapping answers.

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Aha, a sign of active and healthy community.

Comment: maybe the command should be `\renewenvironment` ? I use your code and got an error: `Command \Question already defined.`. However `\renewenvironment` worked.

Comment: @Syvshc You are right. Answer is updated.

Answer (score 9):

The command `\Question` is defined to represent the double question mark character, along with a whole bunch of other unicode character mapping definitions ("mathtable"), done at begin document. You should choose a non-clashing environment name.

I agree it is annoying that `\Question` isn't defined immediately by unicode-math, so it would be detected by the `\newcommand`; and unicode-math issues no warning about the changed definition when it does get defined. (The command that fails to give warning is `\__um_sym:nnn`.)

But why is there no double-question character in the output?? There *WILL* be a warning in the log file explaining that:

```
Missing character: There is no ⁇ in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Comment: Will Robertson is active here and can speak to this if he feels like it, but I’m guessing the reason for silently redefining many commands after the preamble is that people **often** load `unicode-math` over another package whose commands it redefines, such as `mathtools`.

Comment: ...kind of active...

Comment: both your answers are excellent. And I give the acceptance to @muzimuzhi for giving out the solution. ;) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Davislor, you are probably right about the command overwrites.

Comment: Excuse me: you need to use `\tracinglostchars = 2` to get TeX engines to complain when a glyph is missing from a font, instead of silently putting a warning in the middle of the log file.